# I get "Invalid Plugin Options" Error with Prismic Plugin in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, yarnpkg, prismic.io

I'm using CodeSandbox to make a Gatsby app and I'm trying to use Prismic for the backend. I set it up nicely, I'm sure, and I installed `gatsby-source-prismic` to my project. However, when I add it to my config file and restart the project, it throws an error saying "Invalid Plugin Options". This is what's in my plugin file:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-prismic`,
  options: {
    repositoryName: `firstprism`,
    accessToken: `XXX`
  },
},
```

Here's the stack:

```
 ERROR
```

gatsby-source-prismic - invalid plugin options

ERROR

Expected a value of type `record<string,object>` for`schemas` but received `undefined`.

Error:

- index.cjs:650 new StructError
  [sandbox]/[superstruct]/lib/index.cjs:650:19
- index.cjs:707 Function.Struct.assert
  [sandbox]/[superstruct]/lib/index.cjs:707:13
- index.cjs:679 Struct
  [sandbox]/[superstruct]/lib/index.cjs:679:19
- gatsby-node.js:74 validatePluginOptions
  [sandbox]/[gatsby-source-prismic]/dist/gatsby-node.js:74:50
- gatsby-node.js:1042
  [sandbox]/[gatsby-source-prismic]/dist/gatsby-node.js:1042:25
- Generator.next
- gatsby-node.js:52
  [sandbox]/[gatsby-source-prismic]/dist/gatsby-node.js:52:71
- new Promise
- gatsby-node.js:48 __awaiter
  [sandbox]/[gatsby-source-prismic]/dist/gatsby-node.js:48:12
- gatsby-node.js:1029 Object.sourceNodes
  [sandbox]/[gatsby-source-prismic]/dist/gatsby-node.js:1029:55
- api-runner-node.js:256 runAPI
  [sandbox]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:256:37
- api-runner-node.js:375 resolve
  [sandbox]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:375:15
- debuggability.js:384 Promise._execute
  [sandbox]/[bluebird]/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9
- promise.js:518 Promise._resolveFromExecutor
  [sandbox]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:518:18
- promise.js:103 new Promise
  [sandbox]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:103:10
- api-runner-node.js:374 Promise.mapSeries.plugin
  [sandbox]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:374:12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this issue. It appears it is now required to provide JSON schemas, as described here in the docs : https://github.com/angeloashmore/gatsby-source-prismic#providing-json-schemas

edit: please also refer to https://github.com/angeloashmore/gatsby-source-prismic/blob/master/docs/migrating-from-v2-to-v3.md

Comment: YES it's so funny because I actually figured it out earlier today and realized when I added the schemas as an option it worked splendidly. But thanks a lot.

Comment: Correct updated documentation is https://github.com/prismicio/prismic-gatsby/blob/main/docs/02-set-up-prismic.md

Answer (score 0):

It's like this

```
options: {
        repositoryName: 'your-repository-name',
        accessToken: `${process.env.API_KEY}`,
        linkResolver: ({ node, key, value }) => post => `/${post.uid}`,
        schemas: {
          page: require("./src/schemas/page.json"),
        },
      },
```

instead of this now

```
options: {
        repositoryName: `your-repository-name`,
        accessToken: `${process.env.API_KEY}`,
        linkResolver: ({ node, key, value }) => post => `/${post.uid}`,
        page: require("./src/schemas/page.json"),
      },
```